# Adding a case-sensitive to OData in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, odata

I've added a OData v4 to my WebApi and it works great. I followed this instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/getting-started

However, I noticed, that I need a case insensitivity. I found a solution in C#: [OData and .NET Core 2 Web API - disable case-sensitivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347919/odata-and-net-core-2-web-api-disable-case-sensitivity)

But somehow it does not work for me. When I try it out, it says:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '[my url]'.

Register method that works:

```
Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    builder = New ODataConventionModelBuilder()
    builder.EntitySet(Of vw_CompanyPerson)("profiles")
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel())

    config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(Nothing).Count()
End Sub
```

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports Guestline.RezLynx.Persistence
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions
Imports Microsoft.OData
Imports Microsoft.OData.UriParser

Public Class WebApiConfig

    Private Shared Property builder() As ODataModelBuilder

    Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        builder = New ODataConventionModelBuilder()
        builder.EntitySet(Of vw_CompanyPerson)("profiles")

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "odata",
            "odata",
            New Action(Of IContainerBuilder)(AddressOf ModifyContainer))

        config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(Nothing).Count()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub ModifyContainer(obj As IContainerBuilder)
        obj.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, New Func(Of IServiceProvider, ODataUriResolver)(AddressOf CreateUriResolver))
        obj.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, New Func(Of IServiceProvider, Edm.IEdmModel)(AddressOf GetEdmModel))
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetEdmModel(arg As IServiceProvider) As Edm.IEdmModel
        Return builder.GetEdmModel()
    End Function

    Private Shared Function CreateUriResolver(arg As IServiceProvider) As ODataUriResolver
        Return New CaseInsensitiveUriResolver()
    End Function

End Class
```

And:

```
Imports Microsoft.OData.UriParser

Public Class CaseInsensitiveUriResolver
    Inherits ODataUriResolver

    Public Overrides Property EnableCaseInsensitive As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)

        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I turned out that I was not returning `IQueryable` interface and comparison was done in code, rather than on database. Once I used `IQueryable`, SQLs were generated the right way and comparison was done correctly.

Pro tip: use SQL Server Profiler to check your requests to DB!